# Unity movement instant stop

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem in unity where when I move my character it stops moving and I have to move to a different direction and then return to the original direction to be able to move here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed=5f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Debug.Log(horizontal);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity= new Vector2(speed*horizontal,rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

_ The horizontal input works normally when the problem happen
_ There is no specific location where the character gets stops
Can you give me any possible solutions

Comment: btw I tried another script and it didn't work

Comment: Please stick to your question and stop re-posting the exact same one over and over again